# Pass variables from lwc to another lwc while creating record

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm new to Lightning Web Components and want to know the best way to create/modify a custom object record in one lwc and then update another lwc on the same page to display data based on the record being created/modified. Basically, I would need an Id so I could retrieve the record and make it display based on the record's values.

I guess I don't know what the best architecture for this. Can someone point me to an *example* of something close to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Aura to achieve this result we use force:RecordData and with LWC we must use lightning-record-form.

Here is the link for the documentation on how to use it:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-form/documentation

Hope it can help!